# In Vue3, how to get data attribute of parent element and pass to component prop

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

In a Vue3 template, how do you access parent element data attributes and pass them into the prop of a Vue component?

Example code:

```
  <div data-pagenumber="23" class="printed-page">
    <!-- ...         -->
    <!-- OTHER STUFF -->
    <!-- ...         -->
    <SomePagingComponent :number="<I-need-pagenumber-passed-into-here>" />
  </div>
```

Where `data-pagenumber` is just an HTML attribute (external source) on the parent, `SomePagingComponent` is a Vue component and `:number` is a prop for the component.

Past answers exist for Vue2 and talk about accessing `this.$parent` or `$attrs`, however I'm not seeing any of this accessible in a Vue3 template and/or they come out as blank.

Context: I'm using Vue to generate pages for printing (or PDF output) and everything works. I'm attempting to enhance the app by dynamically generating additional pages if content overflows any given page... ***after*** the DOM renders. When doing so, I re-calculate page numbers (e.g. "Page 3 of 20") and would like to store this paging data as HTML attributes (for cleanliness). I can find a different way of course.

Comment: can your parent component pass the attribute values as props?  The child can continue passing props to the grandchild.  Child components should ideally know as little about their parent as possible to maintain separation of concerns.  There is also [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) and [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) as alternative options

Comment: Ya I could create a proper page component, which may open some doors. Up to this point I've kept the project structure very flat; everything in a single `App.vue`. I may need a `Page.vue` anyways if I'm about to be generating new component instances dynamically. In any case, I'm still curious about passing data-attributes.

Comment: This looks like XY problem. "store this paging data as HTML attributes (for cleanliness)" - you shouldn't do this in a properly written Vue app, there's nothing clean in this approach. The component is supposed to be data-driven, the value `23` needs to be available in component script. You technically can get this value in component script from dom

Comment: Do you have direct access to parent element or it creates dynamically?

Comment: @MMDM The interaction between siblings is handled by a parent. You need to do this in a component that hosts <div data-pagenumber="23">. If there's no component then create one. You can likely access it as this.$el.parentNode.dataset.pagenumber inside SomePagingComponent but that's garbage code tbh

Comment: @EstusFlask Hi, I thinks you replied wrong on me!

Comment: @MMDM Confused you with the OP indeed, sorry

Comment: @EstusFlask No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ref` on the component itself then use native javascript `parentElement` to access its parent div attributes

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue
const SomePagingComponent = {
    setup() {
    const paging = ref(null)
    const number = ref( 0 )
    onMounted(() => {
      const parent = paging.value?.parentElement
      number.value = parent?.getAttribute('data-pagenumber') ?? number.value
    })

    return { paging, number }
  },
    template: `
    <div ref="paging">
        loaded component
        <h3>Page Number from parent div: {{ number }}</h3>
    </div>
    `
}
const app = createApp({})
app.component('paging', SomePagingComponent)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div data-pagenumber="23" class="printed-page">
        <paging/>
    </div>
</div>
```